# React.js If Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having difficulties writing an if statement in React (bit new to this)

```
class TEST extends React.Component {
render() {
    const TEST = props => {
        if (props.isLoggedin("True")) {
            return (
                <Welcome />
            );
        }
        return (null);
    };
   }
 }
export default Switch(TEST);
```

The error message that I am getting is:

> Your render method should have return statement

Not sure the best way to write this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `const TEST = props => { }` part, other than that looks okay.

Try as the following:

```
class TEST extends React.Component {
  render() {
    if (this.props.isLoggedin("True")) {
       return <Welcome />;
    }

    return null;
  }
}

export default Switch(TEST);
```

Or even shorter with [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```
class TEST extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return this.props.isLoggedin("True") ? <Welcome /> : null;
  }
}
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanks, but then it errors as Props is not defined - 'props' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: @user3665791 Probably you need `this.props` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you wanted to do something like this:

```
class TEST extends React.Component {
   render() {
      if (this.props.isLoggedin("True")) {
          return (
              <Welcome />
          );
      }
      return (null);
   }
 }
```

Or this (if you want to use functional components):

```
const TEST = props => {
    if (props.isLoggedin("True")) {
        return (
            <Welcome />
        );
    }
    return (null);
  };
}
```

You could also do it like this:

```
const TEST = props => props.isLoggedin("True") && <Welcome />
```

What you actually had is that you **only defined** a function inside your render method, that expected a `return` statement.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#function-and-class-components